# Rendering Twig template in PHP template

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am rendering a PHP template with Symfony 2, the template code I have:

`phptemplate.html.php`:

```
...
<?php echo $view->render('MyBundle:Def:info.html.twig', array('m' => $m)) ?>
...
```

`MyBundle:Def:info.html.twig`:

```
abc
{{ url('form_individual') }}
{{ m.test }}
abc
```

**Output display result**:

```
abc
{{ url('form_individual') }}
{{ m.test }}
abc
```

Variables are not rendered but instead are displayed as text, why?

Comment: did you have defined the doctype ? Also what is `test` ? If it's a block, then you've defined it incorrectly.

Comment: i replace test to abc - this is nothink its string rendered on page. Where i defined doctype ?

Comment: other twig templates not rendered in php template work without problems

Comment: $m is object send from phptemplate.html.php

Comment: `echo get_class($view)` what do you get?

Comment: i get Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\TimedPhpEngine

Answer (score 1):

`PhpEngine`, which in fact you used, doesn't support `twig` templates. So, your`twig`template is (probably) parsed as a plain text.

`PhpEngine` `supports` method [Source code](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Templating/PhpEngine.php#L124) and [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Templating/EngineInterface.php#L63) base doc for `supports` where is: `Returns true if this class is able to render the given template.`.

Why you didn't rewrite your `MyBundle:Def:info.html.twig` template to php? Or parent one to `twig`?